# python matplotlib convert string variable to axes attributes

Tags: python, variables, matplotlib, axes

I am not really a python guy. I am coming from Fortran background and trying to understand object-oriented programming, so please forgive me if my questions are silly!
I have the following simple piece of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.6,0.6])

a = ax1
ya = 'yaxis'

x = np.linspace(0.0, 2.*np.pi)
a.ya.set_ticks_position('left')

a.plot(x,np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

Now I want to assign a variable `ya` the axes attribute `yaxis`. Obviously `'yaxis'` is string so `ya` will be a string variable. 
So, my code fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t.py", line 14, in <module>
    a.ya.set_ticks_position('left')
AttributeError: 'Axes' object has no attribute 'ya'
```

I see the reason for this (because `ya` is a string variable and `a` is a class object and expects an attribute of some data type). My questions is how do you convert the `ya = yaxis` to a proper variable that `a` or `ax1` will accept. I know in this case it is sort of redundant doing it but eventually I will be looping over many axes and their attributes e.g. `(ax1, ax2.......)` and `xaxis, yaxis` and I don't want to have them hard coded.
Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the built-in functions `getattr` and `setattr`.

```
getattr(object, attrname)
setattr(object, attrname, value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer and explanation!

Comment: It's not that this would actually answer the question, or does it?. See the marked duplicate on how to use a strings as attribute.